# Is price parity legal in France?

Tags: internet, france

Is price parity legal in France?

I want to sell items on a French website which has requirements to provide the best price available.
The contract includes the following:

“In order to maintain the attractiveness of the Marketplace for Users and Sellers, the
Price of the Products indicated on the Marketplace shall not be higher than the price(s), if
any, charged by the Seller for the same Products via other distribution methods and/or
sales channels (physical and/or online).”

I was reading that price parity is not legal in the hotel industry in France: https://www.yieldplanet.com/france-prohibits-rate-parity-clauses-by-law/

But what about e-commerce?

Answer (score 1):

The law as described in the linked article is specific to contracts between hotels and booking agencies. it will not affect similar agreements for sellers of online goods. Unless there is some **other** law making such agreements illegal for e-commerce transactions, such an agreement would be legal.

The article says that this is the first law of its type in Europe. That suggests, but does not prove, that there is no other such law currently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
1.according to this link
https://businessblog.trivago.com/rate-parity-hotel-industry-status/
The have a visual explaining price priority and on it for France it writes
“All rates priority closures banned”
Does that mean that is for all industries?

Comment: 2.If prior to signing the agreement by email a representative from the marketplace writes in email that
“The issue you had is you wanted us to remove the price parity clause. I said we are unable however told you in writing that you were fine to overlook this clause. “

Will we still be committed to the contract?